# Looking for a PHP's str_split() replacement

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have this little piece of code:

```
<?php 
$tmp = str_split('hello world!',2);
// $tmp will now be: array('he','ll','o ','wo','rl','d!');
foreach($tmp AS &$a) {
  // some processing
}
unset($tmp);
?>
```

How can I do this in Python v2.7?

I thought this would do it:

```
the_string = 'hello world!'
tmp = the_string.split('',2)
for a in tmp:
  # some processing
del tmp
```

but it returns an "empty separator" error.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I almost forgot, the PHP's documentation for str_split: 
http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php

In the foreach loop I created $a passed as reference, this is correct because I manipulate $tmp before destroying it later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(the_string), 2):
    print(the_string[i:i+2])
```

Comment: Or to return a list: [s[x:x + 2] for x in range(0, len(s), 2)]

Answer (score 3):

`tmp = the_string[::2]` gives a copy of the_string with every second element. ...[::1] would return a copy with every element, ...[::3] would give every third element, etc.

Note that this is a slice and the full form is list[start:stop:step], though any of these three can be omitted (as well as step can be omitted since it defaults to 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [24]: s = 'hello, world'

In [25]: tmp = [''.join(t) for t in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])]

In [26]: print tmp
['he', 'll', 'o,', ' w', 'or', 'ld']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def str_split_like_php(s, n):
    """Split `s` into chunks `n` chars long."""
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, len(s), n):
        ret.append(s[i:i+n])
    return ret
```

Comment: I guess I still think "natively" in loops, then optimize down to comprehensions later, and I skipped the second step!